# Argo with multiple GCP projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, argoproj

I've been looking into Argo as a Gitops style CD system. It looks really neat. That said, I am not understanding how to use Argo in across multiple GCP projects. Specifically, the plan is to have environment dependent projects (i.e. prod, stage dev). It seems like Argo is not designed to orchestrate deployment across environment dependent clusters, or is it?

Comment: What is the identity of your Argo pipeline? Have you a service account?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Not sure what you mean by that. I am new with Argo, looking into it as a potential CD option.

Comment: Where will you run your Argo app? on GKE?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, on GKE. I'd like to merge from dev -> stg -> master in Github and have that kick off Argo deploying versions to corresponding environments. Perhaps the solution is to simply deploy an Argo server in each GCP project and have them all point to separate branches? Maybe that is the simplest approach? How can I have Argo deploy the applications to the various environments along with environment dependent configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is mainly about security management. You have several possibilities and several point of views/level of security.

**1. Project segregation**

The most simple and secure way is to have Argo running in each project without relation/bridge between each environment. No risk in security or to deploy on the wrong project. Default project segregation (VPC and IAM role) are sufficient.

But it implies to deploy and maintain the same app on several clusters, and to pay several clusters (Dev, Staging and prod CD aren't used at the same frequency)

In term of security, you can use the Compute Engine default service account for the authorization, or you can rely on [Workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) (preferred way)

**2. Namespace segregation**

The other way is to have only one project with a cluster deployed on it and a kubernetes namespace per delivery project. By the way, you can reuse the same cluster for all the projects in your company.

You still have to update and maintain Argo in each namespace, but the cluster administration is easier because the node are the same.

In term of security, you can use the [Workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) per namespace
(and thus to have 1 service account per namespace authorized in the delivery project) and to keep the permission segregated

Here, the trade off is the private IP access. If your deployment need to access to private IP inside the delivery project (for testing purpose or to access to private K8S master), you have to set up a VPC peering (and you are limited to 25 peering per project) or set up a shared VPC.

**3. Service account segregation**

The latest solution isn't recommended, but it's the easiest to maintain. You have only one GKE cluster for all the environment, and only 1 namespace with Argo deployed on it. By configuration, you can say to Argo to use a specific service account to access to the delivery project (with service account key files (not recommended solution) stored in GKE secrets or in secret manager, or (better) by using service account impersonation).

Here also, you have 1 service account authorized per delivery project. And the peering issue is the same in case of private IP access required in the delivery project.